# Powerpoint 2010: Master/Child documents

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, child-document

I want to edit my presentation in a more structured manner, so I am searching for a way to split the presentation into child documents. The solution should ideally allow

- Editing subsets of the slides as separate file
- Allow presenting all files as one combined presentation, without creating a merged `.ppt(x)` file.
- Allow exporting the combined presentation as PDF.
- Synchronize changes to the slide master across the files (optional)
- Number slides consecutively across the files (optional)

If this isn't possible I can fall back to merging the slides when editing is finished, but I'd prefer the slides to remain in separate files for future editing.

In Word, this would be achieved by using a **master document** with separate child documents.

Comment: If you're connected to a SharePoint server you can try using [slide libraries](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Slide-Libraries-to-share-and-reuse-PowerPoint-slides-c419e77f-8a94-4fc1-a7f0-f5e6cdd7e419) for this purpose.

Comment: I am not. It is about documenting my PhD work in a presentation meant to be adapted and reused over time, meant to reside a a single folder on my local PC.

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for but you can embed (and link) a child presentation in another presentation. When presenting you will have to click to activate each child presentation so you won't get the seamless transition between slides or continuous numbering, but you will be able to keep each child pptx on its own and reflect changes wherever it is embedded. Exporting multiple files to PDF can be solved with a macro.